# About oscillations in a time-delayed power system

Tags: power, delay, oscillation

I'm new here so pls correct me if there's anything inappropriate.

For a power system without delay, we can calculate its eigenvalues, where each pair of the complex eigenvalue represents an oscillation mode. The imaginary part represents the oscillation frequency. For a multi-area system, we can use modal analysis to determine whether this eigenvalue belongs to an inter-area oscillation, which has 0.5-1Hz of frequency and a very low damping ratio.

Here's my question:

Now if there are one or multiple time-delays in this system, the system's dimension becomes infinite, which means there are infinite numbers of complex eigenvalues.

1. Does each pair of complex eigenvalues still represents an oscillation mode, which can be seen from appropriate simulation?
2. Are there anyways to identify the participation factor in this condition while there's no left-eigenvector matrix and right-eigenvector matrix? If not, are there anyways to identify if this eigenvalue is an inter-area oscillation.
3. I know we can calculate the eigenvalue sensitivity to the time-delay, in this condition, while the time-delay change, the eigenvalue will change, i.e., the oscillation frequency will change. Does that mean there will be inter-area oscillation with a pretty high frequency (>1Hz) if we have a large delay?
4. In a delay-free system, are there any conditions that give the possibility of a high-frequency inter-area oscillation?

I have read several papers about inter-area oscillation and delayed system. However, there's very few intersections of them. The paper about delayed system focus on its stability (rightmost eigenvalue) and I'm open to any discussion or document recommendation.

Thanks very much!